# Bypass default caching policy if file is managed by service worker

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I am using Google's `workbox-cli` tool in order to precache some of the files on my website. Is it possible to setup the webserver to return the following in the HTTP response header for all files by default:

```
cache-control: s-maxage=2592000, max-age=86400, must-revalidate, no-transform, public
```

**But**, have the webbrowser use the follwing instead only if the file is going to be precached by the service worker:

```
cache-control: s-maxage=2592000, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform, public
```

So, I would like the service worker to change `max-age=86400` into `max-age=0` in the webserver's response header before precaching the file. This makes the service worker fetch files, that have changed according to the revision in `sw.js`, from the webserver instead of retrieving them from local cache. Any files not managed by the service worker are cached for 86400 seconds by default.

### Some background info

Currently, I am using the following bash script to setup my `sw.js`:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d /tmp/workbox-configuration ]; then
mkdir /tmp/workbox-configuration
fi
cat <<EOF > /tmp/workbox-configuration/workbox-config.js
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "harp_output/",
  "globPatterns": [
EOF
( cd harp_output && find assets de en -type f ! -name "map.js" ! -name "map.json" ! -name "markerclusterer.js" ! -name "modal.js" ! -name "modal-map.html" ! -name "service-worker-registration.js" ! -name "sw-registration.js" ! -path "assets/fonts/*" ! -path "assets/img/*-1x.*" ! -path "assets/img/*-2x.*" ! -path "assets/img/*-3x.*" ! -path "assets/img/maps/*" ! -path "assets/img/video/*_1x1.*" ! -path "assets/img/video/*_4x3.*" ! -path "assets/js/workbox-*" ! -path "assets/videos/*" ! -path "de/4*" ! -path "de/5*" ! -path "en/4*" ! -path "en/5*" | sort | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/' | sed -e '$ ! s/$/,/' >> /tmp/workbox-configuration/workbox-config.js )
cat <<EOF >> /tmp/workbox-configuration/workbox-config.js
  ],
  "swDest": "/tmp/workbox-configuration/sw.js"
};
EOF
workbox generateSW /tmp/workbox-configuration/workbox-config.js
sed -i 's#^importScripts(.*);$#importScripts("/assets/js/workbox-sw.js");\nworkbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: "/assets/js/"});#' /tmp/workbox-configuration/sw.js
sed -i 's/index.html"/"/' /tmp/workbox-configuration/sw.js
uglifyjs /tmp/workbox-configuration/sw.js -c -m -o harp_output/sw.js
```

On my Nginx webserver the following HTTP header is delivered by default:

```
more_set_headers "cache-control: s-maxage=2592000, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform, public";
```

But, if the requested ressource is not handled by the service worker, the default `cache-control` setting is overwritten:

```
location ~ ^/(assets/(data/|fonts/|img/(.*-(1|2|3)x\.|maps/|video/.*_(1x1|4x3)\.)|js/(map|markerclusterer|modal|service-worker-registration|sw-registration)\.js|videos/)|(de|en)/((4|5).*|modal-map\.html)) {
    more_set_headers "cache-control: s-maxage=2592000, max-age=86400, must-revalidate, no-transform, public";
}
```

### Problem with the current approach (see background info)

1. I have to keep track of the files and update `nginx.conf`correspondingly.
2. `max-age=0` is used also for webbrowsers that don't support service-workers. So, they request the ressources from the webservers on each page visit.

### 1st Update

My desired precaching behaviour can be illustrated with two of the [workbox strategies](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies). I want the service worker to show below behaviour as described in scenario 1 and 2, although `cache-control: max-age=86400` is delivered in the HTTP header by the webserver for an asset (e.g. `default.js`).

**Scenario 1: revision in sw.js didn't change**

The webpage is accessed, the `sw.js` file is retrieved from the webserver due to `max-age=0` and the webbrowser noticed that the revision for `default.js` didn't change. In this case, `default.js` is retrieved from the precache cache:

[image]

**Scenario 2: revision in sw.js did change**

The webpage is accessed, the `sw.js` file is retrieved from the webserver due to `max-age=0` and the webbrowser noticed that the revision of `default.js` changed. In this case, `default.js` is retrieved from the webserver:

[image]

### 2nd Update

Basically, the desired strategy is similar to the [network-first strategy](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#network_first_network_falling_back_to_cache). But, step 2 is only taken if the revision of the file in `sw.js` has changed.

[image]

### 3rd Update

If I am not mistaken, there is already [some work](https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/) on this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(`static-${version}`)
      .then(cache => cache.addAll([
        new Request('/styles.css', { cache: 'no-cache' }),
        new Request('/script.js', { cache: 'no-cache' })
      ]))
  );
});
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#explanation_of_the_precache_list  maybe review docs can help. The precache may take some of this off your plate if u can coordinate with the event  that install/re-install the SW , dragging along cache refreshed items in process

Comment: @RobertRowntree I am already using workbox's precache module. The linked doc doesn't cover any setting which makes the service worker retrieve changed ressources from the webserver instead of the local cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `s-max-age` instead of `s-maxage` in the `cache-control` HTTP header, which lead to some unexpected behaviour with my reverse proxy and workbox service worker. After the fix, the service worker is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a comprehensive enough understanding of how service workers actually work.

You define one, or many caches for a service worker to use. You specify what goes in which cache, whether to cache future requests etc

The service worker now intercepts all network requests from the client and then responds to them however you have programmed it to. It can return cached content if available, cached content first while updating over the network, network first and copy to cache in case of no connection, cache for images but not for anything else, only cache GET requests, only cache certain domains, file types etc......

What it caches and for how long each cache is valid is entirely up to you and not influenced by server response headers at all. If you tell your service worker to make a fetch request for a resource then it will load that resource over the network, regardless of any headers or what is already cached locally.

You have total control over the entire caching process, which is very useful but has it's own set of pitfalls.